# Ubuntu 17.10 new install, Firefox 57.0 (64-bit) can't play videos on Google Photos

Tags: firefox, 17.10, google

Brand new install of 17.10, love it so far.  I especially love the new Firefox browser but I can't seem to get my videos to play on photos.google.com.  All I get is a static screen with "This video format is not supported".

I did install Chrome and they do play through that browser, so I know I'm just missing something on my Firefox install.  I tested Flash and that seems to work on the Adobe flash test site after I allow it, but I never get a prompt to allow Flash on the Google photos page, I assume they're using something else anyway.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 3):

Finally worked this one out, totally forgot about the unrestricted extras.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

After that I restarted Firefox and all was well.

You can check your video codec status at:

https://www.youtube.com/html5

After you install the unrestricted extras package the H.264 and MSE & H.264 should be blue with a check.